# How to connect pg Admin 4 to PostgreSQL which is deployed in a Docker container

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I have created an ASP.NET Core application. This application allows you to use a PostgreSQL database through the Entity Framework Core ORM. Everything works fine on the local database. The problems started when I tried to create docker application containers and databases. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  naladimbot:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}naladimbot
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NaladimBot/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 23r2323ffsedsEGDS#%23EAF
      POSTGRES_DB: NaladimBot.Database
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes: 
  db: 

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

And this is my connection string in the file appsettings.json :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=23r2323ffsedsEGDS#%23EAF;Database=NaladimBot.Database;"
}
```

The problem is this: when I build my application in docker-compose mode, everything works fine. Docker Desktop introduces application containers and databases.

[image]

But when I try to connect to the db database via pg Admin 4 (a container that I also created in Docker) - nothing happens. Docker suggests `http://localhost:5432/` for the connection, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Also instead of localhost I tried 0.0.0.0 , 172.18.0.1 , 172.18.0.2 - the result remains the same.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The server `localhost` here refers to the container running PgAdmin and there's no postgres running it.

Use `db` as a host when you try to connect since they're both on the same network `mynetwork`.